# jQuery .data doesn't work when using a html jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem using the `.data` jQuery function for a HTML jQuery Object.

```
var test = $('<div><div class="abc123"></div></div>');
test.find('.abc123').data('please', 'change');
```

and `test` still hasn't changed at all

```
<div>
    <div class="abc123"><div>
</div>
```

But using the `.text` function

```
test.find('.abc123').text('TESTING');
```

works properly:

```
<div>
    <div class="abc123">TESTING</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make the `data` work on the `test` var?

---

Edit:

What i am expecting after running

```
test.find('.abc123').data('please', 'change');
```

is

```
<div>
    <div class="abc123" data-please="change"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the HTML of `.abc123` to change?

Comment: I am expecting it to show `<div class="abc123" data-please="change"></div>`

Comment: jQuery's .data() method doesn't change the attribute but is managed internally by jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.data()` on an element, whether created in HTML or in a JQuery object will not modify the associated markup. Regardless, the associated DOM properties *are* updated.

```
var test = $('<div><div class="abc123"></div></div>');
test.find('.abc123').data('please', 'change');

alert(test.find('.abc123').data('please'));
```

The above code will alert 'change'.

If your goal is to also update the markup, you could instead use:

```
test.find('.abc123').attr('data-please', 'change');
```

Comment: Oh this is interesting, just checked this, and you are right! Thank you!